# how to read and write url content into a file using angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

by using this code i can able to open the link i want..but I want to read that particular content of the url and write it into the notepad using ANGULAR JS ..
this is 6the code i used..

HTML and JAVASCRIPT

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
   <head>
    <script>
    function start_scroll_down() { 
     scroll = setInterval(function()
     { window.scrollBy(0, 1000);           
      console.log('start');}, 1500);
     }

     function stop_scroll_down() {
      clearInterval(scroll);
     console.log('stop');
     }
   </script>
     <button onclick="start_scroll_down();">Start Scroll</button>
    <button onclick="stop_scroll_down();">Stop Scroll</button>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com
     /ajax/libs/angularjs/1.1.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngFileSaver']);

    app.controller('myCtrl', ['$http','FileSaver', 
     'Blob', function($http, FileSaver, Blob){
    $scope.foo = function() {
     $http.get('http://www.thehindu.com/news/').
           success(function(pageContent){               
       var data = new Blob([pageContent],
       {type: 'text/plain;charset=utf-8' });
     FileSaver.saveAs(data, 'text.txt');            

   });

   };  
      }]);
  </script>
    <meta charset=utf-8 />
     <title>JS Bin</title>
    </head>
      <body>
    <a href="http://www.thehindu.com/news/" target="_blank">News</a>
    <button ng-click="foo()">News</button>
    </body>
     </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a module like the [angular-file-saver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-file-saver). It might be slightly involved - but the steps are outlined on the module's NPM page.
Basically, you need to install the `angular-file-saver` module and then modify your `myApp` module to inject it like this:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngFileSaver']);
```

//You also need to change your controller to include the FileSaver and Blob params:

```
app.controller('myCtrl', ['$http','FileSaver', 'Blob', function($http, FileSaver, Blob){
   //now you can use the file save inside your $scope.foo like this:
      $scope.foo = function() {
        //get content of the remote URL (take care of the CORs)             
         $http.get('http://www.thehindu.com/news/').success(function (pageContent){               
          //here you create file and save content to it
           var data = new Blob([pageContent], {type:   'text/plain;charset=utf-8' });
        FileSaver.saveAs(data, 'text.txt');            

      });

      };  
}]);
```

I hope that helps, give it a try and let me know how it goes;

Comment: Cool, if it helps - please come back and accept the answer so your question can me marked off as answered. Happy coding!

Comment: by using  filesaver.js..is it possible to download a aprticular url content?

Comment: It is used for saving content to file - I proposed it to show you how you can save content of the file - to retrieve content of a remote page (URL) you might need to use `$http` - but that's not really in scope of this question. Test if the "saving of file" works- so we close this - and we can look at retrieving remote content in a separate question.

Comment: i tried and i can able to download a file ...thanks..but here my question is to  read and write url content (webpage content)into a text file using angular js

Comment: Great! Let me show how you can retrieve content off  the URL.

Comment: Please see **UPDATED** answer with how to retrieve content of the page using `$http`.

Comment: Please check with Developer Tools to see if there are any errors. You can test with your localhost as the URL just in case there may be issues with Cross Origin...

Comment: i have these two errors in the console..                                                   Error: No module:ngFileSaver      and   SecurityError: The operation is insecure.

Comment: Please update your code in the question so we can see what you have and try to resolve the issues - I suggest you also test with your localhost - just to confirm that the code work (retrieving page content);

Comment: Your JavaScript code - is it on a separate script or in the same file as the HTML?

Comment: in  same file as the HTML

Comment: OK, just to be sure, please show your complete HTML (which includes the Javascript parts) - I can then try and reproduce your problem this side - the complaint about the module might indicate that there are errors somewhere in the definition of the Controller.