# read the content using angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to hit the URL and download the file using angularjs.
Below is the link i reffered and took code:
[how to read and write url content into a file using angular js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40355576/how-to-read-and-write-url-content-into-a-file-using-angular-js)

My code demo [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/zKSeGyGndHIrr4x6cwsv?p=preview)

I have taken FileSaver.js from https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js

js code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.1.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="FileSaver.js"></script>
    <script>
        function start_scroll_down() {
            scroll = setInterval(function()
            { window.scrollBy(0, 1000);
                console.log('start');}, 1500);
        }

        function stop_scroll_down() {
            clearInterval(scroll);
            console.log('stop');
        }
    </script>


    <script>
        var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngFileSaver']);
        app.controller('myCtrl', ['$http','FileSaver','Blob', function($http, FileSaver, Blob){
                $scope.foo = function() {
                    alert("foo");
                    $http.get('http://www.thehindu.com/news/').
                    success(function(pageContent){
                        alert("success");
                        var data = new Blob([pageContent],
                                {type: 'text/plain;charset=utf-8' });
                        FileSaver.saveAs(data, 'text.txt');

                    });

                };
            }]);
    </script>
    <meta charset=utf-8 />
    <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="start_scroll_down();">Start Scroll</button>
<button onclick="stop_scroll_down();">Stop Scroll</button>
<button ng-click="foo()">Newsww</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Any suggestions?I want to hit the https URL and read the content/download the file.

Comment: Your plunker link fails.

Comment: @MikeFeltman - I have updated, please find the link https://plnkr.co/edit/zKSeGyGndHIrr4x6cwsv?p=preview